# A special type of an integral equation

Tags: integration

I am doing a research paper and I faced with this problem. Does anyone know the answer (or an approximation for the answer) for the following
integral equation?
$$\int_0^{y(x)} e^{-xt}f(t)dt = g(x)$$
We want to find $y(x)$. In case it  is necessary, we know that  $y(0)=0$ and $g(0)=0$. We know that $f(x)$ is probability density function and $\int_0^\infty$f(x)dx=1.

Comment: Please give more background to the problem.Like its origin. Also, it is not clear what do you mean by "find". Are there information? (like $f$ is continuous)

Comment: It was actually a problem in a digital communications system.  yes $f$ is continues. Also, $f$ is a probability density function. I added this information.

Comment: Is $g(x)\neq0$ for $x\neq0$? If not, the solution would not be well-defined given this information, since at any point where $g(x)=0$, $y(x)$ could be any negative number. Just something to notice.

Comment: Yes $g(x)\neq 0$ for $x\neq 0$.